# New Silverlight version - trouble : automatically update in OOB mode

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob

I have a signed XAP (Silverlight version  4.0.50401.0) installed with elevated trust in OOB.

Each new version of XAP was successful installed in OOB mode (automatically download and ...) - all work as expected.

Now I installed **latest Silverlight development stuff** (now I have Silverlight **4.0.50917.0**).

All my clients who run my app in browser - require to update their Silverlight runtime - all work as expected - nice Silverlight update dialog, install new Silverlight runtime, etc.

**Problem with my OOB installed clients - they silence ignore this new version of XAP**.

**Why after I update my Silverlight development stack does the OOB auto-update facility stop working** and why doesn't an OOB installation have a mechanism for checking and updating the Silverlight runtime version? Maybe one exists and I don't know.

Thank you.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight actually throws an `PlatformNotSupportedException` exception if the update requires a newer version of Silverlight so you should catch and handle that to alert the user to download a new version.

> If an application update is available,
>   but uses a newer version of
>   Silverlight that the user has not yet
>   installed, the update will not be
>   downloaded. This also occurs if an
>   update changes the application to
>   require elevated trust. In both cases,
>   the `UpdateAvailable` property value is
>   false, and the Error property value is
>   an Exception instance. With a
>   Silverlight version change, the
>   exception is a
>   `PlatformNotSupportedException`
>   instance. With a security change, the
>   exception is a `SecurityException`
>   instance. When this happens, you can
>   alert the user to open the
>   application's host Web site,
>   triggering your HTML-based Silverlight
>   upgrade experience.

Out of Browser Support on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721(v=VS.95).aspx